# powershell as gvim(vim) :shell

Tags: windows-7, powershell, vim

i'm on a Windows 7 machine and i've installed Gvim(win32 version not MinGW or something alike), i've written in my _vimrc

```
set shell=powershell.exe
```

Now when i type :shell command it must open a new buffer with powershell in it but instead it opens powershell in a new window.

Question : Is there a way to set Gvim ( configuration or plugin ) to open PowerShell in a buffer (like bash)?

Comment: This isn't what you asked, but if you run vim from powershell you should get the behaviour that you're after.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Reread documentation for `:shell` and `design-not`. Quote from design-not:

   > Vim is not a shell or an Operating System.  You will not be able to run a
   >   shell inside Vim or use it to control a debugger.  This should work the
   >   other way around: Use Vim as a component from a shell or in an IDE.
   >   A satirical way to say this: "Unlike Emacs, Vim does not attempt to include
   >   everything but the kitchen sink, but some people say that you can clean one
   >   with it.  ;-)"
2. Of course, somebody does not like this. There are some projects that make it possible to run shell inside vim, most known is [Conque](http://code.google.com/p/conque/) which now has windows support. Note that it does not work with unicode.