# Setting up Powershell as Vim's shell: command does not seem to be passed correctly

Tags: powershell, vim

I am trying to set up Powershell as shell in GVIM on Windows.

When I do `:!ls`, I get a `vimrun.exe` window with the command I am running, which seems to be doing nothing. It stays like that until I close it.

[image: vimrun.exe output]

---

My `.vimrc` configuration:

```
set shell=powershell
set shellcmdflag=-command
set shellquote=\"
set shellxquote=
```

Nothing interferes with it: when I do `:verbose set shell? shellcmdflag? shellquote? shellxquote?` I get the values set above.

When I remove `vimrun.exe` from `%PATH%`, I get a Powershell window, which is just empty (no output in it) with same behavior.

The command itself is fine - when I execute it manually from cmd, it works as expected.

When Vim shell is set to cmd, everything works as expected as well.

There are questions that may seem related, but are not same:

- [gvim on windows 7 - vimrun.exe doesn't run command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910924/gvim-on-windows-7-vimrun-exe-doesnt-run-command)
  (very similar problem, but with `shell=cmd`, which is not my case)
- [Vim with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94382/vim-with-powershell)
- [Using PowerShell as VIM shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742781/using-powershell-as-vim-shell)
- [powershell as gvim(vim) :shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358740/powershell-as-gvimvim-shell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the issue was in 32-bit powershell not working correctly on my system (yet to figure out why). I changed `set shell=powershell` to:

```
set shell=C:\\WINDOWS\\sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe
```

That launches 64-bit powershell, which works fine on my system.

Comment: On my end it does work, but i have to execute the command everytime i open nvim. do you have to set it up everytime too?